# Setting python list and dictionary to None takes a lot of time

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have this code:

```
        rows_to_process = EulerNightlyDBQueries.fetchRowsToProcess(cur_date, Config.config_dict['settings']['Performance']['euler_nightly_rows_to_process'], Config.config_dict['settings']['Data']['recover_mode'])
        mac_uniques_hour, \
        emp_mac_uniques_hour, \
        mac_uniques_hour_monthly = EulerNightlyDBQueries.fetchMacUniquesByDate(cur_date)

        #Start processing raw rows from receiver table
        try:
            RawProcessor.startRawProcessor(cur_date, mac_uniques_hour, emp_mac_uniques_hour, rows_to_process)
            emp_mac_uniques_hour = None
            rows_to_process = None
```

notice the 'rows_to_process' (list of rows from the DB) and the 'emp_mac_uniques_hour' (dictionary of values from the DB).

Lets say I have 800,000 rows fetched for each one of them.
When I do the:

```
emp_mac_uniques_hour = None
rows_to_process = None
```

It takes 45 - 120 seconds!!
Isn't it just changing the reference of the list and the dictionary to None??
Why is it taking so long..??

I'm doing this in order to the GC to be able to collect them after I'm done with them..
By the way, I'm using python 2.7.6

Thanks!

Comment: how do you measure time for that particular assignment, can you show men the code for that ?

Comment: No code is needed.. I just have a lot of debug prints who also print the current time. And right before the None part (at the end of the startRawProcessor function) I have print of time, and right after the None part..

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing this in order to the GC to be able to collect them after I'm
>   done with them.. By the way, I'm using python 2.7.6

That's not how CPython's GC works. It primarily does reference-counting, and only does mark-style GC as a last resort to detect reference loops. So if that's the last reference to the object, then setting it to `None` will free the object (and so on recursively).

If you would like to postpone the necessary GC work until later, you could create another reference to the data, and set *that* to None later. Or I suppose you could try to contrive a reference loop, but that seems complicated.

Still, 2 minutes feels to me like a lot for under a million database rows.

Comment: I don't want to postpone the GC work.. I want to to be able to collect those 2 object before the end of the function.. Isn't setting them to None meaning the the now have no reference and the GC can collect them in its next run? even if the function didn't end..

Comment: @OrKazaz: if there are no references to the objects, then the GC will not collect them "in its next run". They are freed immediately, and that's what's taking a long time (maybe a lot of data is paged out, do you see a lot of disk activity?). I don't really understand how you can firstly say that you don't want to postpone the work, and secondly say that you don't want it to happen now, you want it to happen "in the next run". Surely that would be postponement?

Comment: I may not understand something.. I'm coming from .Net world.. There the GC will clean up the memory but I can't control when (unless using the GC.collect.. but leave that..), I can only know that objects without references will be collected and freed.
Here in python isn't it the same?
When there is no reference to the object the GC will collect it immediately??

Comment: Look up "reference counting". I mentioned it for a reason ;-)

Comment: I know what is "reference counting" :-)
But what you say, that unlike .Net, python free the memory immediately? And still, why is it stopping my code? Isn't it happening at the backgroud..?